# Using Oracle APEX, how do I accomplish these tasks (customizing a simple SQL report)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to make the following customizations to a basic APEX database-table dump :

1. The user also needs to be able to edit the data displayed in the grid.
2. The user needs to be able to add new rows to the grid and enter values
3. Above each column heading there needs to be a text field where the user can enter a value
4. To the right of the data grid, there needs to be a search button that will re-display the data in the grid using the values entered above the column heading. If there fields are blank all possible values for that field should be returned
5. There should be a save button on the page to allow the user to save data they have entered/ updated in the grid

I wanted to know about whether these were possible with APEX, and how do I accomplish these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like an Interactive Report:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/irrs-083031.html

( I know linking to another site with the answer is sometimes frowned upon but there just isn't enough room here for a complete tutorial ;) )

Comment: Thanks ! I think this is it - I found something called an "Data Reporter" (it's an app inside APEX) , and it gives these options

Comment: IRs are not inherently editable.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - So does that mean, for example, that I couldn't be able to rename a column in an IR ?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - ah nevermind - i figured this out now ( "quick edit" option on the bottom menu )